# How to remove non-symmetric pairs in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, idioms

Given a numpy Nx2 numpy array `data` of ints (we can assume that `data` has no duplicate rows), I need to keep only the rows whose elements satisfy the relationship

```
(data[i,0] == data[j,1]) & (data[i,1] == data[j,0])
```

For instance with

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 2], 
                 [2, 1],
                 [7, 3],
                 [6, 6],
                 [5, 6]])
```

I should return

```
array([[1, 2], # because 2,1 is present
       [2, 1], # because 1,2 is present
       [6, 6]]) # because 6,6 is present
```

One verbose way to do this is

```
def filter_symmetric_pairs(data):
  result = np.empty((0,2))
  for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data)):
      if (data[i,0] == data[j,1]) & (data[i,1] == data[j,0]):
        result = np.vstack([result, data[i,:]])
  return result
```

and I came up with a more concise:

```
def filter_symmetric_pairs(data):
  return data[[row.tolist() in data[:,::-1].tolist() for row in data]]
```

Can somebody suggest a better numpy idiom?

Comment: What if some row is repeated? Say last row is `[7,3]` ?

Comment: Is it an ineteger array ? Then you can use some hash based approach (like set) to test the candidacy efficiently. As for floating point '==' is a dead end. You will need to check the abs/rel diff against an eps. That along with sorting array and binary search can do the job.

Comment: @Divakar et al, I clarified the question a bit (it's ints, and you can assume no duplicate rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of different methods you may use to do that. The first one is the "obvious" quadratic solution, which is simple but may give you trouble if you have a big input array. The second one should work as long as you don't have a huge range of numbers in the input, and it has the advantage of working with a linear amount of memory.

```py
import numpy as np

# Input data
data = np.array([[1, 2],
                 [2, 1],
                 [7, 3],
                 [6, 6],
                 [5, 6]])

# Method 1 (quadratic memory)
d0, d1 = data[:, 0, np.newaxis], data[:, 1]
# Compare all values in first column to all values in second column
c = d0 == d1
# Find where comparison matches both ways
c &= c.T
# Get matching elements
res = data[c.any(0)]
print(res)
# [[1 2]
#  [2 1]
#  [6 6]]

# Method 2 (linear memory)
# Convert pairs into single values
# (assumes positive values, otherwise shift first)
n = data.max() + 1
v = data[:, 0] + (n * data[:, 1])
# Symmetric values
v2 = (n * data[:, 0]) + data[:, 1]
# Find where symmetric is present
m = np.isin(v2, v)
res = data[m]
print(res)
# [[1 2]
#  [2 1]
#  [6 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the arrays preserving the row contents using `argsort` for both the original and reversed arrays, then just check which rows are equal and use that as a mask for slice `data`.

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2],
                 [2, 1],
                 [7, 3],
                 [6, 6],
                 [5, 6]])

data_r = data[:,::-1]
sorter = data.argsort(axis=0)[:,0]
sorter_r = data_r.argsort(axis=0)[:,0]
mask = (data.take(sorter, axis=0) == data_r.take(sorter_r, axis=0)).all(axis=1)

data[mask]

# returns:
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [6, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution dawned on me, which sees `data` as the edge list of a directed graph and filters only bidirected edges (my problem is thus equivalent to [detecting mutual edges in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553273/detecting-mutual-edges-in-a-graph)):

```
def filter_symmetric_pairs(data):
  rank = max(data.flatten() + 1) 
  adj = np.zeros((rank, rank)) 
  adj[data[:,0], data[:,1]] = 1 # treat the coordinates as edges of directed graph, compute adjaciency matrix
  bidirected_edges = (adj == adj.T) & (adj == 1) # impose symmetry and a nonzero value
  return np.vstack(np.nonzero(bidirected_edges)).T # list indices of components satisfying the above constraint
```